# Heroku + Mechanize turns OBJ into a String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mechanize

So I have an app that uses Mechanize to get a page.  Please note the HTTP site I'm trying to parse is a *.TXT file.

In IRB I run a simple program like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'

@agent = Mechanize.new{|agent| agent.user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:9.0a2) Gecko/20111101 Firefox/9.0a2'}

@agent.get(http://some_sort_of_text_file.txt)

for line in @agent.page.content
puts line
end
```

This runs fine and I get each line in the text file as an output.

But when I push it to Heroku..  I get an error like this:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000003ebf200>):
```

Well... I found out that for some odd reason that the page became one giant string file, which I need to take another step to do some programming like:

```
  @doc = @agent.page.content
      @items =[]
      start =0
      @doc.gsub(/|/, " ")
      @doc.gsub(/\\n/,"|")
      counter=0
      while counter <= @doc.length
         if(@doc[counter]== "|")
           @items << @doc[start..counter]
           start=counter+1
         end
         counter = counter+1
      end
```

Any idea why it takes in the site as a string on Heroku and why I need to take the extra step just to break down each line into an array?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code on my local machine in irb, `@agent.page.content` is a String.

If what you want is to take the result and turn it into an array, this will work:

```
# (put this after @agent.get(http://some_sort_of_text_file.txt)
lines = @agent.page.content.split("\n")

# Now you can do something like this if you want
lines.each do |line|
  puts line
end
```

Comment: This was such an old proj, I put it on the back burner.  Besdies each page was made by a different person so the formatting was wacky so I just gave up.